# Handle Open Square Bracket in NHibernate query for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have the following query code using NHibernate query in C#.

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(String.Format(@"
                select
                r
                from
                Revision r
                where r.Code = :Code
                order by upper( r.Name ), r.SeqNo
                "))

query.SetParameter<string>("Code", CodeValue);
```

I have problem if the value of the variable CodeValue contains character '[' (the Open Square Bracket). Every time it is passed as the value, the SQL Server will return no result.

Advice, please, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
query.SetAnsiString("text", "%" + filter.Text.Replace("[", "[[]") + "%");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Well done, I applied the code just like the one you show here. I found out that '[' is one of the escape character in SQL Server. So, in summary, what we only need to do is manage the text to handle the escape character of SQL Server. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure why you are adding %'s, the query is using = not like.